# Project in C won't work

Tags: c

I need to do a project, and so far I've done this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
typedef struct
{
    char Name[10];
    char Address[10];
    long Phone_number;
}Phonebook;
void main()
{
    int Counter, Number = 0;
    long Number_of_residents;
    Phonebook *Information = (Phonebook*)malloc(sizeof(Phonebook));
    scanf("%ld", &Number_of_residents);
    for (Counter = 0; Counter < Number_of_residents; Counter++)
    {
        Information = (Phonebook*)realloc(Information, sizeof(Phonebook)*(Counter + 1));
        gets(Information[Number].Name);
        Number++;
        gets(Information[Number].Address);
        Number++;
        scanf("%ld", &Information[Number].Phone_number);
        Number++;
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong here?

It doesn't work at all.

Comment: Try `int main(void)`

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own question. (Your recent edit deleted the code and replaced it with "thank you for the help, I've done it.".) If your problem has been solved, leave the question in place so future readers can benefit from the solution. And if one of the posted answers solved the problem, you should accept it.

Comment: Never use `gets()`. It is inherently unsafe, and has been removed from the language as of the C11 standard.

Comment: Stop vandalising your question, leaving answers without context!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need do Number++ after every gets()

There are also couple of bugs in the code, the correct code will looks like. Please note that we don't need to realloc array every time as we know it size before reading each element.

Also using gets() is unsafe and if you start using scanf() it's better to continue use it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
  char Name[10];
  char Address[10];
  long Phone_number;
}Phonebook;

int main() {
  int Counter, Number = 0;
  long Number_of_residents;
  Phonebook * Information;
  scanf("%ld", &Number_of_residents);
  Information = (Phonebook*)malloc(Number_of_residents * sizeof(Phonebook));
  for (Counter = 0; Counter < Number_of_residents; Counter++) {
    scanf("%10s", Information[Counter].Name);
    scanf("%10s", Information[Counter].Address);
    scanf("%ld", &Information[Counter].Phone_number);
  }

  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
typedef struct
{
    char Name[10];
    char Address[10];
    long Phone_number;
}Phonebook;
void main()
{
    int Counter;
    long Number_of_residents;
    scanf("%ld", &Number_of_residents);
    getchar();
    Phonebook *Information = (Phonebook*)malloc(Number_of_residents * sizeof(Phonebook));
    for (Counter = 0; Counter < Number_of_residents; Counter++)
    {
        gets(Information[Counter].Name);
        gets(Information[Counter].Address);
        scanf("%ld", &Information[Counter].Phone_number);
        getchar();
    }
}
```

The changes made:

1. As said in the existing answer, `Number++` was incorrect. In fact, you don't need `Number` at all. You can simply use `Counter`.
2. `scanf()` has issues with `\n` being taken as the next input, so I have added `getchar()` after every `scanf()` to take care of that.
3. I am not sure why you had that `realloc()` statement. I removed it, and now this code snippet that I have posted works on my computer.

Comment: When you have removed realloc() there would be a problem with memory... Because in malloc() you have allocated the space only for one element.

Comment: Well our answers look almost the same. But there are still some minor differences so I'll let mine be.